# Python function for finding if all substrings exist in a string in sequence

Tags: python, regex

I want to find if all of a list of substrings exist in a string, in the correct order (with or without spaces between them),  it seems to be a good use for regex.

I think I need to build a regex filter of `"a.*b.*c"` and use search to find that anywhere in my string.

Are there any other approaches I could consider or built in functions that might do this for me?

```
from re import search

def are_substrings_in_text(substrings,text):
    
    return search("".join([s+".*" for s in substrings]),text) is not None                  

print(are_substrings_in_text(["a","b","c"],"abacus")) # >True
print(are_substrings_in_text(["a","c","b"],"abacus")) # >False
print(are_substrings_in_text(["a","c","z"],"abacus")) # >False
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your current approach is that it can give incorrect results
or raise an exception if any of the substrings contain characters that
have special meaning in Python regular expressions.

```
are_substrings_in_text(['a', '.', 's'], 'abacus'))   # Returns True
are_substrings_in_text(['a', '+', 's'], 'abacus'))   # Raises exception
```

The solution is to escape such characters so that they are handled as
literal substrings. This illustration also makes a few cosmetic adjustments
to simplify things for readability:

```
from re import search, escape

def are_substrings_in_text(substrings, text):
    pattern = '.*'.join(escape(s) for s in substrings)
    return bool(search(pattern, text))
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using `'.*'.join(escape(s) for s in substrings)`?

Comment: @AJNeufeld I blame my aging mind.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't necessary to use regular expressions (the re module), use the `str.index()` method. For the examples given, `re.search` takes 3x longer.

```
def are_substrings_in_text_index(substrings, text):
    start = 0
    try:
        for substring in substrings:
            start = text.index(substring, start) + len(substring)
            
        return True
    
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Comment: Good point on the performance, thanks! It seems to vary depending on the relationship between the number of substrings and the length of the text;  I guess in a real scenario one would model it with realistic data to see the best approach, If it was really time critical. I also noticed that "if substring not in text" is significantly faster than either;  and regex REALLY struggles with near-misses. So a filter pass to see if at least each character exists in the text will speed up finding non-matches massively too.